# Source Control Explorer Shows Pending Changes, But In Pending Changes Window does not show

Tags: tfs

In TFS Source Control Explorer it shows pending changes (edit,[more]) with my name, but the Pending Changes window does not show any pending changes.

What I thought is, months ago my Visual Studio crashed, and at that time some files were checked out (which I was not aware of, due to the automatic checkout nature of TFS). Due to that, I copied a new VMImage, without undoing the pending changes (which are currently showing in Source Control Explorer).

One of my team members wants to checkin a new version of that particular file. Now, I need to undo my pending changes.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you have them checked out under a different workspace.  Try going to View->Other Windows->Source Control Explorer, then open the Workspace dropdown near the top of the screen, and select "Workspaces..."

I would suggest simply deleting any extra workspaces shown.

Comment: One more thing to add here IN VS 2015.
Open the Workspace drop-down near the top of the screen, and select "Workspaces..."-->At the bottom of the opened Pop-up-> Choose "Show Remote workspaces" and you will see all the workspaces where you have mapped.

Comment: I  mapped to one of the colleague's boxes sometime and I forgot and one file got checked out on his box and on my box, I never saw anything checked out to me so I went ahead(following above comment) and deleted the remote workspace and that resolved that mysterious checkout.

Answer (score 4):

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Make non-conflicting edits to files in TFS.
2. Get the latest version of the project from source control.
3. Sometimes, pending changes will be marked as non-pending and all project files are saved, resulting in no pending changes in the Team Explorer.

**Workaround:**

1. Right-click on the solution folder in source code explorer
2. Select "Compare"
3. In the search results, manually open files which have been edited/added and save them.  This will register them as a "Pending Change" in team explorer.

This is because TFS apparently uses file properties rather than actual text comparisons to register pending changes in Visual Studio.

Tested on:  Windows 7, Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

**Additional feedback from my supervisor:**  "Not sure if it was the issue this time, but that can happen when you disconnect from the TFS server (which sometimes happens without it being obvious). File | Source Control | Go Online usually fixes it (and the option isn’t available if you are online)."

Comment: Hello, this is happening to me right now, is there a way to make this automatic, so i dont have to to visual studio and safe file by file since i use webstorm to edit my javascript projects. thank you.

Comment: @LexyFeito I sometimes have luck going offline then back online with TFS for the projects that are suffering issues. Beyond that, I'm not aware of any way to make TFS recognize these updates automatically.

Answer (score 2):

TFS is buggy everywhere. i think you need to check out the parent folder and use TFS power toys to undo all the rubbish unchanged item.
TFS use file property to indicate whether or not a file has change, which sucks the most, and produce tons of usability problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the file that you checked out is not part of the current solution, it might be hidden by the "Filter by solution" toolbar button on the Pending Changes window.

Answer (score 2):

Get your changed files **check out for edit**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I re-started VS, opened the solution and all the changes are now being displayed in the pending changes window.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to checkout the file from the Source Control Explorer view ?

For me, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a similar issue in **VS2012**.

To resolve the issue, I toggled the "Show xxx" dropdown to "Show Solution Changes" and then back to "Show All".  The files that were missing from the list then re-appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and it was due to the fact that my local version was a "non-version control solution" for some reason! meaning that my local was not really connected to the actual source code on tfs.

fix: Got the latest with override option checked. I know this could be painful if you had a lot of changes made to your local.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue the first answer was really helpfull. But make sure to check "Show Remote Workspaces" if you are working from different computer. In my cases the files where checked in and edited from home computer and it was showing pending changes. Deleting unwanted workspaces helps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

- a different workspace on the same machine
- a different workspace on another machine
- TeamExplorer -> PendingChanges -> Excluded Changes ( I included this only because you didn't specifically mention they weren't there)

  - especially if you right clicked a node in solution explorer and chose check-in
- Filtered based on TeamExplorer Settings [@Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673026/57883)
- Use a Tfs Query to find the pending changes and what workspace they are pending from.

Another option is to permanently or temporarily give them permissions to overwrite your lock. Then he can check-in anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem. Sometimes when I have the pending changes window in 'flat display mode', it doesn't display my changes. I find if I click the toolbar icon at the top of the pending changes window with tooltip 'Change to folder view', then they display. I think this is a bug in the Team Explorer Client.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I can not lock a branch because users have things checked out, but when I ask them about it, the pending merges/changes, only folders come up with no objects to change. What's with that?

Comment: This should be a comment or a separate question, not an answer.