# Eclipse TFS branch show also changes in root

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm using Eclipse importing TFS projects, one project is:

$/product mapped to C:\dev\product

I opened a branch and started working on different workspace:

$/product-branch mapped to C:\dev-branch\product

I worked on each project successfully

But now in branch in TFVC Pending Changes I see changes I made (checkouts) also in C:\dev\product ($/product)

Why am I seeing such changes and How can I separate those branches when I switch to different workspace?

**EDIT**
My TFS 2010 is using server workspace.

Comment: Are you using server workspace or local workspace? Sounds like you are using a server workspace.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT  server workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TFVC workspace is the container for all of the work that should be grouped together (think of it like the contents of a Git repository). Now if you open a sub-folder of a Git repository in Eclipse and you've made changes at a folder that's higher up (that is, one you didn't explicitly open), the Git SCM still shows those files. It doesn't only show the files modified for the folder that you've got open. That's the same behavior as what the TFVC support is currently showing.

If you are using server workspace and checked out work under a different workspace, it will also show pending changes in pending changes list.   Take a look at this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/423439/5391065

As a workaround, you could temporarily **exclude** no need changes in another branch to exclude list.

[image]

Comment: I need to keep excluding every time files added in different workspace?

Comment: @user7294900 Or you could switch to local workspace , it will only detect changes for separately workspaces, haven't tested in eclipse ,but this work properly in visual studio, should be the same. Take a look at the difference of server workspace and local workspace: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/28/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces/